# add new values to bootstrap ui-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-select

Is there any way to add a value which is not present in the list to ui-select. Tagging is available in multi-select but doesn't work for ui-select.
If not, is there any other library I can make use of?

```
<ui-select ng-model="model.Array[$index]" reset-search-input="true">
    <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected}}
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="value in List| filter: $select.search | orderBy:value |limitTo:100">
        <div ng-bind-html="value| highlight: $select.search "></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Comment: You can manually add values  to the array. Please provide your code for what you did.

Comment: Please add your code .

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean free-form tagging?  If so, this is supported.  Please see the example file [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/examples/demo-tagging.html).

Per the request below, [here's a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XJaLyWqiiD9MkBAJt74f) with the example and the HTML portion of the source is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="demo">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS ui-select</title>

  <!--
    IE8 support, see AngularJS Internet Explorer Compatibility http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie
    For Firefox 3.6, you will also need to include jQuery and ECMAScript 5 shim
  -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/2.2.0/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.createElement('ui-select');
      document.createElement('ui-select-match');
      document.createElement('ui-select-choices');
    </script>
  <![endif]-->

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">

  <!-- ui-select files -->
  <script src="select.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="select.css">

  <script src="demo.js"></script>

  <!-- Select2 theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.css">

  <!--
    Selectize theme
    Less versions are available at https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/tree/master/dist/less
  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.8.5/css/selectize.default.css">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.8.5/css/selectize.bootstrap2.css"> -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.8.5/css/selectize.bootstrap3.css"> -->

  <style>
    body {
      padding: 15px;
    }

    .select2 > .select2-choice.ui-select-match {
      /* Because of the inclusion of Bootstrap */
      height: 29px;
    }

    .selectize-control > .selectize-dropdown {
      top: 36px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <script src="demo.js"></script>

  <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="enable()">Enable ui-select</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="disable()">Disable ui-select</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="clear()">Clear ng-model</button>

  <h1>Tagging Demos</h1>

  <h3>Simple String Tags</h3>
  <h4>(With Custom Tag Label / Sort Enabled)</h4>
  <ui-select multiple tagging tagging-label="(custom 'new' label)" ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" theme="bootstrap" sortable="true" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;" title="Choose a color">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
      {{color}}
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
  <p>Selected: {{multipleDemo.colors}}</p>
  <hr>

  <h3>Simple String Tags </h3>
  <h4>(Predictive Search Model / No Labels)</h4>
  <ui-select multiple tagging tagging-label="false" ng-model="multipleDemo.colors2" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;" title="Choose a color">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
      {{color}}
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
  <p>Selected: {{multipleDemo.colors2}}</p>
  <hr>

  <h3>Object Tags</h3>
  <ui-select multiple tagging="tagTransform" ng-model="multipleDemo.selectedPeople" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 800px;" title="Choose a person">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select person...">{{$item.name}} &lt;{{$item.email}}&gt;</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
      <div ng-if="person.isTag" ng-bind-html="person.name +' <small>(new)</small>'| highlight: $select.search"></div>
      <div ng-if="!person.isTag" ng-bind-html="person.name + person.isTag| highlight: $select.search"></div>
      <small>
        email: {{person.email}}
        age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
  <p>Selected: {{multipleDemo.selectedPeople}}</p>
  <hr>

  <h3>Object Tags with Tokenization (Space, Forward Slash, Comma)</h3>
  <strong>Note that the SPACE character can't be used literally, use the keyword SPACE</strong>
  <ui-select multiple tagging="tagTransform" tagging-tokens="SPACE|,|/" ng-model="multipleDemo.selectedPeople2" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 800px;" title="Choose a person">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select person...">{{$item.name}} &lt;{{$item.email}}&gt;</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
      <div ng-if="person.isTag" ng-bind-html="person.name + ' ' + $select.taggingLabel | highlight: $select.search"></div>
      <div ng-if="!person.isTag" ng-bind-html="person.name| highlight: $select.search"></div>
      <small>
        email: {{person.email}}
        age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
  <p>Selected: {{multipleDemo.selectedPeople2}}</p>

  <h3>Tagging without multiple</h3>
  <ui-select tagging="tagTransform" ng-model="person.selected" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 800px;" title="Choose a person">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select person...">{{$select.selected.name}} &lt;{{$select.selected.email}}&gt;</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
    <div ng-if="person.isTag" ng-bind-html="person.name +' <small>(new)</small>'| highlight: $select.search"></div>
    <div ng-if="!person.isTag" ng-bind-html="person.name + person.isTag| highlight: $select.search"></div>
    <small>
      email: {{person.email}}
      age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </small>
  </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
  <p>Selected: {{person.selected}}</p>

  <h3>Tagging without multiple, with simple strings</h3>
  <ui-select tagging tagging-label="('new')" ng-model="singleDemo.color" theme="bootstrap" style="width: 800px;" title="Choose a color">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select color...">{{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter: $select.search">
      <div ng-bind-html="color | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
  <p>Selected: {{singleDemo.color}}</p>


  <div style="height:500px"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's fair.  I'm a little disappointed we don't have a working plunker for it so I'll create one out of that example file.

Comment: @Mogsdad  did you vote my answer down?  wtf?  you didn't even give me a chance to fix it.  don't be a troll, dude.